# cpanel file access from vs code using cloudflare

Tags: visual-studio-code, cpanel, cloudflare

I want to access my code from my server in VS code but the problem is I'm using Cloudflare so none of my connection is working neither ftp connection works nor SSH connection works both connection are rejected by Cloudflare.

Is there any way/Cloudflare configuration  to access remote file(code from my cPanel) in my local machine

I also try git push but git push command is also blocked by Cloudflare.

thanks in advance.
I have tried scanning port It says only port 80(http) and port(443) https are open. Port 21 (ftp) and port 22 (SSH) are filtered.

Comment: try ssh connection through ip address because domain ports are blocked by cloudflare you can use port 22 or any port other than 80 or 443 so you can use ip address as a domain to login to the server